# Difference between RMS and PMPO in radio speakers

Tags: sound

The radio speakers come with their loudness unit either in RMS or PMPO watt.

What is the difference between the RMS and PMPO in sound system?

Comment: RMS power is a total fallacy in engineering. Volts or amps can have an RMS value but not power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RMS power value is the real music power output of a speaker. It is a true indication of the output power across the full range of frequencies produced by a given speaker.

PMPO (Peak Music Power) refers to the maximum amount of power output that the speaker could produce if driven to it's peak. A PMPO rating is not indicative of the output of a speaker across a wide frequency range and therefore not particularly useful as an indication of speaker performance.

You cannot compute RMS output from PMPO and vice-versa as they do not measure the same characteristics.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: Just a quick comment, rms power does not exist per se. Power is expressed in watts, obtained from averaging the instantaneous product of current and voltage waveforms. See [here](https://agcsystems.tv/rms-power-fallacy/) and [here](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-177.html#) for more explanations.

Comment: I agree with verbal kint. It's nonsense to talk about RMS power. Power is the average value of volts x amps.